# Header with content

Tags: headers

I want to make a large header with logo, navigation and centered title and some text below. I dont know how to make that centered title and text below so that end user can edit title and text in admin panel.

I have an idea to get some post data into header.

```
        $post = get_post($post_id = 1); 
        echo '<h1>'.$post->post_title.'</h1>'; 
        echo '<p>'.$post->post_content.'</p>';
```

Maybe create special page template for that purpose? How to tell wordpress that this page goes to header.

Comment: How about using the text widget? All you need is registering a place for it with `register_sidebar()`.

Comment: Interesting idea. I need to think about this.

Comment: Maybe I create settings page with 2 textfields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing is based on your template.If your template allow you to add your own code then you can add this code in your template part.
In your active theme you can see **header.php** file, in this file you can add this code where it is suitable.

Comment: I know that. I am creating theme with underscores